# @section @extends are not working laravel. I have checked all the nothing helped

Tags: laravel, extends

I have downloaded a template for my page and i want to put navigation in 1 file. I have tried many ways to do that like:

```
@extends('navigation')  the file is in views. 

@yield('navigation')

@section('navigation')
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img  width='60' src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li ><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about_us">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="blog-item">Blog Single</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="404">404</a></li>
                            <li><a href="shortcodes">Shortcodes</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="{{route('blog.index')}}">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </nav><!--/nav-->
@stop
```

nothing helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the errors? "Not working" is not very detailed.

Comment: Please fix formatting. And then show master blade, actual view file, and the nav file (which you shared already - I'm assuming this is a partial?).

Comment: Ps: `@extends` is to specify your master template. Not to include partials.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you might need to read up on [Laravel blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) a little more. Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell where you're going wrong. But by the sounds/looks of it, you're including the nav file incorrectly and not extending a master template properly.

Here's how this ***should*** work:

***master.blade.php***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        @include('menu.navigation')
        @yield('content')
        @yield('footer')
    </body>
</html>
```

***menu/navigation.blade.php file (change as per your directory structure, etc.):***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img  width='60' src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="blog-item">Blog Single</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="404">404</a></li>
                        <li><a href="shortcodes">Shortcodes</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="{{route('blog.index')}}">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-us">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.container-->
</nav><!--/nav-->
```

***Actual page content (i.e. somepage.blade.php):***

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    // your html code
@stop
```

***If you want `JS` at the end of your master file, like I did here. Just create a section, like so:***

```
@section('footer')

<script>
    $(function() {
        // code
    });
</script>

@stop
```

**This shows you most of the important examples when working with blade templates to get you started on the right path.**

Comment: Helped to add @include('menu.navigaion).Thank you! )